# Is to possible to expose Security Stamp from Asp.Net Core Identity as a claim for OIDC

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity, openid-connect

I am using the `IdentityServer4` with `Asp.Net Core Identity` and I'd like to check in my MVC client (which is connected to IdentityServer4) that User's `SecurityStamp` has changed.

My idea is expose the `SecurityStamp` like a claim in `id_token` and check it in my MVC client in some event in `Cookie` middleware.

If user's security stamp has changed then it will be necessary to login again.

I want to create this round trip especially because I'd like to check if user's roles have changed.

1) Is it good choise to expose `SecurityStamp` like claim?

2) Is there something how to check if user's security stamp is still valid in OIDC? Or it is necessary to build my own endpoint for this one? Like own API?

Answer (score 2):

We've done this and it works well. I return it as the `st` claim in the tokens and also via the user info endpoint so it's easy for clients to check if it's changed.

We then made it a requirement that (internal) clients periodically check via the userinfo endpoint that `st` hasn't changed. We also have a custom impersonation implementation and clients check for impersonation grant revocation the same way.

So in short - yes it's a good idea (IMO) and no you don't need to build an API - just expose it via the userinfo endpoint.

Comment: can you please share some implementation details? Especially how do you check the st claim in client part? Which event in Cookie middleware do you use? Thank you.

Comment: @jenan did you ever get this working yourself, how do you ensure that the security stamp is sent to the userinfo endpoint?

Comment: @Phil I just extended DefaultClaimsService to add in my own claims and implemented my own IUserInfoResponseGenerator which does the same.

Comment: @mackie how did you inject your custom IUserInfoResponseGenerator into identity server services?

Comment: @Phil if you register it in Startup just after you register IdentityServer4 then the new binding will overwrite the default. i.e.: `services.AddTransient<IUserInfoResponseGenerator, CustomUserInfoResponseGenerator>();`